# SQLAlchemy: How to convert a value of a colum in ORM-class

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy do read from a (given) SQLite database. Unfortunately the time value is String and not a TIMESTAMP like "Fri Apr 15 15:57:59 2016"

```
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column('id', String, primary_key=True)
    time = Column('id', String)
```

Is there a way to convert/map instant, so that class.time returns a datetime object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend throwing a property on top of your model:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column('id', String, primary_key=True)
    _time = Column('time', String)

    @property
    def time(self):
        return datetime.strptime(self._time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure that the format for `strptime` is appropriate.  But this way you'll be able to call `.time` and get the appopriate timestamp.

Comment: @chris.stckhmr If you need to be able to query by the `time` column, you may want to consider [hybrid properties](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid) instead.